# Is using traceroute with ICMP echo messages valid?

Tags: icmp, traceroute

Theory says that there shouldn't be any ICMP error messages for ICMP messages. When sending ICMP echo requests in traceroute, doesn't this break this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory you mention was never a standard. In fact, [RFC 1393, Traceroute Using an IP Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1393) created a Traceroute option. This RFC has now been moved to Historic status  by [RFC 6814, Formally Deprecating Some IPv4 Options, Section 2.3.  Traceroute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6814#section-2.3):

> 2.3.  Traceroute
>
> The Traceroute option is defined in [[RFC1393](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1393)].  The Traceroute
> option is defined as Experimental; it was never widely deployed on
> the public Internet.

A Traceroute tool is still part of most OSes, but it is often misused. It is really only useful on a network that you control, and you know what the results *should* be. Using it on public Internet is really a fool's game because many ISPs will purposely reroute the packets and/or set them to lower priority, and your result will not reflect what happens to your other protocols.